# How to make Django show hint's in case password doesn't meet requirements during registration?

Tags: django

Can anyone please tell me how to make Django actually display hints\messages\errors or whatever in case during registration process user's password doesn't meet standart requirements? Because now it is just absolutely silent about that.

Here's my form

```
class Registration(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', ]
```

and here's my view

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Registration(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()  
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('upload')
    else:
        form = Registration()
    return render(request, 'testapp/temp1.html', {'form': form})
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show your template, Django normally renders the form's errors (which will tell the user why their form was invalid) in case it is invalid unless you manually render the fields, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added `{% if form.errors %}` in your template? Something like this:

```
    <!-- START row -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        {% if form.errors %}
          <div class="alert alert-danger">Please fix the following errors:
            {{form.errors}}
          </div>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END row -->
```

Comment: I had no idea form errors are supposed to be rendered! Thank you SO much it works now!